# Using lookup in aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have 2 collections: Order, OrderItem. I'm trying to use lookup to get the OrderItem, and then get the inside them. I followed the docs, and looked at other stackoverflow questions, but nothing worked!

Order schema:

```
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    order_items: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'OrderItem',
        required: true
    }],
    total_price: {
        type: Number
    }
});
```

`module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);`

OrderItem schema:

```
const orderItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    product_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product',
        required: true
    },
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    unit_price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});
```

`module.exports = mongoose.model('OrderItem', orderItemSchema);`

And here's my approach:

```
const totalOrders = await Order.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "OrderItem",
      localField: "order_items",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "ordersItems"
    }
  }
]);
```

I'm getting ordersItems as an empty array!

Can anyone tell me what I'm wrong?
Thanks

Comment: For my own lookups, i use the collection name rather than the mongoose schema name for the from property. As I let mongoose generate the collection names, something like OrderItem for me would end up with a collection called orderitems, therefore my from value would be orderitems, not OrderItem. Have a look in your mongodb and confirm the name of the collection, if its orderitems, use that

Comment: @nimrodserok thank you for your reply. The _id is auto generated when the document is ceated. And I reference it as the ObjectId in the Order document.

Comment: @StevenChristie thank you for your reply.  I edited my question again to show that I export it as a name of my choosing. I looked in my db and confirmed that.

Comment: @StevenChristie was right, if you run `mongoose.model('OrderItem', orderItemSchema);`, mongoose will create a collection named `orderitems` in MongoDB, and that is the name you should use in the lookup.

Comment: this is new to me.. it worked actually!!
thank you both